# Android: How to make fix text of the button when add left drawable

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-button

I have created custom view. In my class i create a button :

```
button = new AppCompatButton(getContext());
LayoutParams button_params = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
button_params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
button.setLayoutParams(button_params);
button.setText(TextUtils.isEmpty(progressText) ? "Button" : progressText);
button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
});
addView(button);
```

I added a drawable to this button like this:

```
   if (isDone) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(progressIconSuccess);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
        button.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, null, null, null);
    }
```

But when drawable added to button, button text shifted to the right :

before drawable added:

[image]

after drawable added:

[image]

I do not want to button text shifted to the right. I want stay fix and do not change its position.How could i do that?

I use my custom view in this way:

```
<com.tazik.progressbutton.ProgressButton
    android:id="@+id/pb_button"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    app:progress_height="30"
    app:progress_width="30"
    app:progress_text = "Register"
    app:progress_iconfail="@drawable/ic_fail"
    app:progress_iconSuccess="@drawable/ic_done"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use new `MaterialIconButton`:

**Button XML code**:

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Icon Button"
     />
```

**Activity code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MaterialButton iconButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testing);

        iconButton=findViewById(R.id.btn);
        iconButton.setIcon(R.drawable.your_icon);
        iconButton.setIconGravity(MaterialButton.ICON_GRAVITY_START);
    }
}
```

Comment: How could i add `setIconGravity` when i create `AppCompatButton` in my class? Because now  i do not have this method in button instance @sumitshukla

Comment: You cannot because it is a property of MaterialIconButton.

Answer (score 0):

Change `progressBar.setVisibility(GONE)` to `progressBar.setVisibility(INVISIBLE)`

As the names suggest when you set visibility to `GONE` the view is "physically" gone - it's not there, while with `INVISIBLE` it's still there, but just not being drawn.

Comment: I changed to `progressBar.setVisibility(INVISIBLE)` but still button's text shifted to the right @miku

Comment: Is it also set to invisible in the xml? It could be that it's gone there so when the app starts it sees it as gone.

Comment: I can not do that because my custom layout extended from `relativeLayoutand` and i make button and progress bar handy and then i added these view to parent layout(RelativeLayout). this is my class https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57352639/android-get-parent-layout-width-in-custom-view-to-set-child-width/57352800#57352800 @miku